# AngularJS nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, nested-loops, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have object which contains question and list of choices. I'm display this object on the page using nested ng-repeats. When I'm trying to change 'question' everything changes just fine, but when I'm trying to change 'choice' nothing happens. Where is the problem?

My page:

```
<div class="panel">

<div class="row">

    <div class="large-12 columns">

        <h3>{{ title }}</h3>

            <ol>
                <li ng-repeat="q in quiz">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="q.question">
                    <ul class="remove-li-dots">
                        <li ng-model="choice" ng-repeat="choice in q.choices">
                            <input type="text" ng-model="choice" name="answer{{ q.id }}" >
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    </br>
                </li>
            </ol>
            <a class="button" ng-click="submitQuiz()">Submit</a><br>
            {{ quiz }}
    </div>

</div>
```

Screenshot of the page:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/i52fwq1os0cvcr9/repeat.png?dl=0

Comment: i think you need to put "q.choices" in {{ }}

Comment: @Bhojendra - C-Link Nepal how to do it in the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that choice is a string, so when you are changing it in child scope it is changing only in child scope.

To fix this - reference it by index in array `ng-repeat="(choiceIndex,choice) in q.choices`,`ng-model="q.choices[choiceIndex]"`.

Also to prevent inputs from loosing focus when changing items - you will need to add `track by $index` in ng-repeat directive.

`<ol>
    <li ng-repeat="q in quiz">
      <input type="text" ng-model="q.question">
      <ul class="remove-li-dots">
        <li ng-model="choice" ng-repeat="(choiceIndex,choice) in q.choices track by choiceIndex">
          <input type="text" ng-model="q.choices[choiceIndex]" name="answer{{ q.id }}">
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ol>`

working example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/GJacjkzfT4FpfC6szsNk?p=preview

---

For better understanding how angular scopes works, I recommend reading this: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Comment: updated an answer for case when using dictionary instead of array, or using filters to arrange items(using `$index` for this purpose, was incorrect)

Comment: Thanks a lot for a detailed answer! I'm new to js and angular seems to me a bit confusing